# how to save two dimensional array values to playerprefs in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 2-dimensional array of Pixel, and have a fill() function to color each element in it.

And now when I color an element, I want to assign it a value of 1, have not assigned it the corresponding 0 value in the array int[,] checkColorPixel in the initialization array of pixels.

This is my code:

```cs
public void CreatePixelMap()
{
    Color[] colors = texture.GetPixels();

    Pixels = new Pixel[texture.width, texture.height];
    int[,] checkColorPixel = new int[texture.width, texture.height];

    for (int x = 0; x < texture.width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < texture.height; y++)
        {
            if (colors[x + y * texture.width].a >= 0.5f)
            {
                Pixel pixel = Instantiate(_pxObj, _trs);
                pixel.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y);
                pixel.transform.name = $"square{x}-{y}";
                Pixels[x, y] = pixel;

                if (!_allTypeOfColor.ContainsKey(colors[x + y * texture.width]))//màu m?i
                {
                    _allTypeOfColor.Add(colors[x + y * texture.width], _countColor);
                    _allPixelGroups.Add(_countColor, new List<Pixel>());
                    _allPixelGroups[_countColor].Add(Pixels[x, y]);
                    Pixels[x, y].id = _countColor;
                    Pixels[x, y]._colorTrue = colors[x + y * texture.width];
                    _countColor++;
                }
                else//màu cu
                {
                    int foundId = _allTypeOfColor.GetValueOrDefault(colors[x + y * texture.width]);
                    _allPixelGroups[foundId].Add(Pixels[x, y]);
                    Pixels[x, y].id = foundId;
                    Pixels[x, y]._colorTrue = colors[x + y * texture.width];
                }
            }

            if (_pxObj.isFlilled == true)
            {
                checkColorPixel[texture.width, texture.height] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                checkColorPixel[texture.width, texture.height] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("CheckColorPixel", checkColorPixel[texture.width, texture.height]);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
    pageSwipe.totalPages = (_countColor - 1) / 10 + 1;
    if ((_countColor - 1) % 10 == 0)
    {
        pageSwipe.totalPages = (_countColor - 1) / 10;
    }
}
```

Fill():

```
public void Fill()
{
    isFilledInTrue = true;
    isFlilled = true;
    _colorRen.color = _colorTrue;
    _lineRen.color = _colorTrue;
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("CheckColorPixel", 1);
    GameManager.Instance.SaveColor();
    _text.text = "";
    _highlight.enabled = false;
}
```

It seems to have failed and reported an error.

Comment: PlayerPrefs in Unity is used to store simple data like integers, floats, booleans, etc.
What I suggest, is to convert your 2d array into a JSON string, but instead of creating a new JSON file you could save the string directly to the PlayerPrefs.

Comment: If you still need help how to do it with a JSON, let me known and I can give you a code example

Comment: thanks , can you give me code example , i need it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[Serializable]
public class SaveData{
   
    public Pixel[,] pixels;
    

}

public static void Save(){
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/save.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        SaveData saveData = new SaveData ();
        bf.Serialize(file, saveData);
        file.Close();
}

public static bool Load(){
        if (File.Exists (Application.persistentDataPath + "/save.dat")) {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter ();
            FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/save.dat", FileMode.Open);
            SerializableSaveData serializableSaveData = (SerializableSaveData)bf.Deserialize(file);
            file.Close();
            serializableSaveData.RestoreSaveData ();
            Debug.Log (SaveData.currentLevel);
            return(true);
        } else {
            return(false);
        }
}
```